# Different data types in update queries

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am executing these two queries.

```
Dim ItemID As String
Dim MemberID As String
Dim updatLibItemSQL As String
Dim DueDate As String

updatLibItemSQL = "UPDATE [tblLibraryItem]"
updatLibItemSQL = updatLibItemSQL & " SET [Status] = '" & inStockString & "',[CheckedOutToMemberID] = '',[DueDate]=''"
updatLibItemSQL = updatLibItemSQL & " WHERE [ItemID] = '" & ItemID & "'"
currDatabase.Execute updatLibItemSQL, dbFailOnError

Dim checkOutReturnSQL As String
checkOutReturnSQL = "UPDATE [tblCheckoutReturn]"
checkOutReturnSQL = checkOutReturnSQL & " SET [ReturnDate] = '" & Date & "'"
checkOutReturnSQL = checkOutReturnSQL & " WHERE [ItemID] = '" & ItemID & "' AND [MemberID] = '" & MemberID & "' AND [DueDate] = '" & DueDate & "'"
currDatabase.Execute checkOutReturnSQL, dbFailOnError
```

If from both queries I remove MemberID and Due Date part, both runs fine. I dont know whats wrong.

In Tables, MemberID is a NUMBER and DueDate is Date/Time Type field. I dont know how to make them empty in first query and how use in where clause in later query.

Please help to correct me, if am wrong

Answer (score 1):

'Empty' is a bit subjective - when you do the initial insert, what values do you give for CheckedOutToMemberID and DueDate?  One simple answer in databases is to use the value NULL. NULL means "doesn't have a value" (actually it can mean anything you want it to mean but we will stick with "doesn't have a value").

In your first query:

```
updatLibItemSQL = "UPDATE [tblLibraryItem]"
updatLibItemSQL = updatLibItemSQL & " SET [Status] = '" & inStockString & "',[CheckedOutToMemberID]=NULL,[DueDate]=NULL"
updatLibItemSQL = updatLibItemSQL & " WHERE [ItemID] = '" & ItemID & "'"
currDatabase.Execute updatLibItemSQL, dbFailOnError
```

In the WHERE part you cannot just say [field]=NULL, that is because NULL isn't  a value - it is a state the field value is in. You have to use the IS operator: [field] IS NULL (or to see if it has a value [field] IS NOT NULL). In your case if you wanted to check that MemberId and DueDate are NULL then use:

```
checkOutReturnSQL = "UPDATE [tblCheckoutReturn]"
checkOutReturnSQL = checkOutReturnSQL & " SET [ReturnDate] = '" & Date & "'"
checkOutReturnSQL = checkOutReturnSQL & " WHERE [ItemID] = '" & ItemID & "' AND [MemberID] IS NULL AND [DueDate] IS NULL"
currDatabase.Execute checkOutReturnSQL, dbFailOnError
```

You can check a field value is NULL in VBA using the IsNull function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278616.aspx

Comment: For second query I dont want to check NULL, They have values in that table

Comment: So how do they store an empty value for MemberID in the table?

Answer (score 1):

A Date field never contains a string; it holds Null or a date/time value.

Thus:

```
Dim ItemID As String
Dim MemberID As String
Dim updatLibItemSQL As String
Dim DueDate As String

updatLibItemSQL = "UPDATE [tblLibraryItem]"
updatLibItemSQL = updatLibItemSQL & " SET [Status] = '" & inStockString & "',[CheckedOutToMemberID] = '',[DueDate] = Null"
updatLibItemSQL = updatLibItemSQL & " WHERE [ItemID] = '" & ItemID & "'"
currDatabase.Execute updatLibItemSQL, dbFailOnError

Dim checkOutReturnSQL As String
' DueDate must hold a string like "2015/11/28":
' DueDate = Format(somedatevalue, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
checkOutReturnSQL = "UPDATE [tblCheckoutReturn]"
checkOutReturnSQL = checkOutReturnSQL & " SET [ReturnDate] = #" & Format(Date, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
checkOutReturnSQL = checkOutReturnSQL & " WHERE [ItemID] = '" & ItemID & "' AND [MemberID] = '" & MemberID & "' AND [DueDate] = #" & DueDate & "#"
currDatabase.Execute checkOutReturnSQL, dbFailOnError
```